# (JAVA) How open a temp htm file in browser?

Tags: java, file, browser, temp

I tried this, but without sucess:

```
         File temp = File.createTempFile("document", ".htm");

         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
         out.write("hi !!!"); 
         out.close();

         System.out.println(temp.toURI().toString());


         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(temp.toURI());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in slightly modified form:

```
    File temp;
    try {
        temp = File.createTempFile("document", ".htm");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
        out.write("hi !!!");
        out.close();

        System.out.println(temp.toURI().toString());

        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(temp.toURI());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```